# cout elements inside array bug,error?

Tags: c++

Need help every time I enter the elements inside the array and print it out, the second elements gives me a random number. For example: array[1,2,3] --> print out : 1, 45234, 3   ---> but always the second number.

```
int main ()
{
    int i,n;
    int * p;
    cout << "How many numbers would you like to type? ";
    cin >> i;
    p = new (nothrow) int[i];

    for (n=0; n<i; n++)
    {
        cout << "Enter number: ";
        cin >> p[n];
    }
    cout << "You have entered: ";
    for (n=0; n<i; n++){
        cout << p[n] << ", ";
        delete[] p;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's with this `p = new (nothrow) int[i];`? Do you know what this line even means?

Answer (score 1):

Move the delete operator outside the loop

```
for (n=0; n<i; n++){
    cout << p[n] << ", ";
}

delete[] p;
```

Also I would add printing the new line character

```
for (n=0; n<i; n++){
    cout << p[n] << ", ";
}
cout << endl;

delete[] p;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the array after you print the first element. You should delete it after the loop finishes